# Java casting conversion?

Tags: java

What does java compiler do in this case ?

```
for(int i=3;i< Math.sqrt(n);i=i+2)
```

`Math.sqrt` returns a `double`, so does Javac widen `i` to a `double` ?

If I want to use the `int` value back will i need to re-cast it ?

How does this actually work ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `i` is widened to a temporary `double` for the comparison. The value of `i` itself is unaffected.

Answer (score 2):

> Math.sqrt returns a double, so does Javac widen i to a double?

Yes

> If I want to use the int value back will i need to re-cast it?

Yes

> How does this actually work ?

With primitives if you have a type that is *wider* than the other in the operation, the smaller is automatically converted for you.

Comment: Explain what you mean on the second point.  To use an `int` as an `int`, you never have to cast it to an `int` even if it's been implicitly converted during a comparison.

Comment: For reference http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/conversions.doc.html#170983 5.6.2 Binary Numeric Promotion

Answer (score 1):

What the language rules say is that i will be promoted to a double, and then compared with the return value of sqrt.

The compiler is free to do whatever it likes, as long as it results in the same behaviour.

I would be surprised if any compiler did anything other than promoted i to a double and did a comparison. The promotion is easy and cheap on most architectures. A *correct* alternative which was faster would be very hard to come up with.

Answer (score -3):

There's no widening in Java, in the sense that is implied by the question: "the compiler widens i to a double". If you define a variable as int, it will always be an int. Internally, the representation of some types may be wider than necessary (for instance, a short may be stored as 4-bytes rather than 2), but this is not affected/determined by the way the variable is used.

Specifically, in the loop describes in the question the compiler emits code that converts the double returned from `Math.sqrt()` into an integer.

You can think of it as if the compiler rewrites the code as follows:

```
for(int i=3; (double) i < (Math.sqrt(n)); i=i+2)
```

(thanks to the people who commented. Fixed the snippet)

Comment: It's not; i is promoted, not the other way around.

Comment: There's no widening in the sense that is implied by the question "the compiler widens i to a double". If you define a variable as int, it will always be int. Internally, the representation of some types may be wider than necessary (for instance, a short may be stored as 4-bytes rather than 2), but this is not affected/determined by the way the variable is used.

Comment: josh, Ernest - I stand corrected I accidentally wrote the wrong casting. Fixed it now.

Comment: Your code snippet is still incorrect. It's as if the compiler rewrites the code as `((double) i) < Math.sqrt(n)`

Comment: I think I know what Itay is trying to say in his comment.  The type of the variable i is not changed, however the value i at the point of comparison is converted to a double and essentially stored as a temporary variable (of type double) for the comparison.

Comment: @vickirk has it exactly right, but @Itay's code is still showing the opposite.